# How to get the time when @Schedule is triggered

Tags: java, calendar, schedule

I was wondering how can I get the time at any one of point of the schedule task method when @Schedule method is triggered. I have tested using Calendar.getInstance() but the timing does not match.

E.g.
At 2pm the @Schedule is triggered
While the Calendar.getInstance() return is before 2pm

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: I just found a link that stated the Calendar.getInstance() may not be accurate - https://community.oracle.com/thread/1261944

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do--are you trying to retrieve, from within the method, a timestamp for when it's called? Why not just grabbing the current system time?

Comment: Actually when I am trying to do is to run 2 schedule on the same method. Lets say 2pm and 4pm the method will be triggered and then I am trying see if currently is 2pm or 4pm and get criteria statement accordingly. I uses Calendar.getInstance() to get the system time. What do you mean by "grabbing current system time" ? How do you do so ?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: There is not much difference between Calendar.getInstance() and System.currentTimeMillis() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004160/difference-between-system-currenttimemillis-and-date-gettime

Comment: `currentTimeMillis()` has a whole lot less overhead, but it may not do quite what you need. In any case, the solution is almost certainly to be running separate methods, using configuration to select between them, instead of hard-baking this kind of decision into the code (which will be flaky anyway, since servers are usually on UTC and not local time).